# Sqlite3 - Parameterisation in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am quite new to SQL and Python and try do dynamically update some entries in my db through a Python script with Sqlite3.

I am using

```
cur.execute('''update Listings set ('%s') = ('%s') where listing_id = 806890652''' % (key, value))
```

which works generally well but sometimes gives errors like 'unrecognized token: "5EDC775CA4B2C_1320"' which I understand is due to the format. I have also read that a better format would be to use (?), (value,) format as it's more proper.

I cannot figure out how to use this format for the above statement (i.e. multiple arguments). What is the correct syntax for this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'd better use the following (assuming you use Python 3):

```
cur.execute(f"UPDATE Listings SET {key}=? WHERE listing_id = 806890652", (value,))
```

So, you would use f"" construct to inject key into the string, and "?" construct to set SQL parameter.

Comment: any reason you are using once {key} and once '?' and not 2x '?' or {key}{value}. Keen to understand the reasoning.

Comment: I believe SQL cannot parameterize column names. Thus I build a string with {} to contain  actual column name, while the value can be parameterized - hence "?".
For example, if your key is "title" and your value is "my title" then the string will be evaluated to something like `cur.execute("UPDATE Listings SET title=? WHERE listing_id=806890652", (value,))`
...which in turn will convert into `"UPDATE Listings SET title='my title' WHERE listing_id=806890652"`

Comment: I see. however, your suggestion throws the following error: InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Try splitting the sentence into two: 
`sql = "UPDATE Listings SET {key}=? WHERE listing_id = 806890652"`
and
`cur.execute(sql, (value,))`
Error will not disappear, but you will see which part of the code generates it.
Either key or value is not suitable here.